# Is every non-empty subset of a vector space always a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If so, how do we prove this?
If not, give an example to disprove this

Comment: Add some context by stating your thoughts/attempts on the problem.

Comment: If the answer is positive, then *at least* the zero vector must belong to your *every non-empty subset*.

Answer (score 1):

Being a subspace is not a small property; it means, for instance, that if a vector is contained in the subset, that every scalar multiple of the vector must be contained in it as well. (And this is not sufficient, just necessary -- you also need to be closed under vector addition, etc.)

So, take any subset that doesn't satisfy this property.  For instance, if your vector space is $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the subset $\{(1, 0)\}$ is not a subspace.